# Avoid junk zero values in double variable

Tags: c++, double

In my below program,

```
main
{
  // value is 476 
  int value = 476;

  // here dimension shows as 0.100000001
  float dimension = 0.1f;



 /// Here I am expecting value as 47.6,
 /// But it gives value as 47.600002288818......
 double result = value * dimension;
}
```

I want to save the value directly in database, So is there any inbuild function to get the expected value ?

Expected : 47.6 instead of 47.600002288.....

Comment: In case you are wondering why this is happening: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/669576).

Comment: The value `47.6` does not exist in any binary floating point type, you can only get approximations. What's your database type?

Comment: Learn about how floating point numbers are stored in memory as every programmer should.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: You omitted the details of how you actually formatted the value: when done correctly, it should print a decent value. However, with the given code it is unlikely that a decent value is actually computed: you'd probably have better luck using `double dimension(10); double result(value / dimension);`.

Comment: Yes I understood. But I am looking for a code snippet/ function to get the result as 47.6 only

Comment: @AneeshNarayanan Then you plainly *don't* understand. It's impossible to get the exact value 47.6 in a `double` on your system.

Comment: Or is there any way to set precision ?

Comment: *Please* read this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) - all of it (twice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways, but in all cases you will have to figure out and decide how many digits of precision your floating point values should represent. There's nothing about a `float` that says "I'm actually .1 instead of 0.100000001".

Once you decided on, say, that your values should carry two digits of precision, there are a few ways to round them off. One simple way is to use stream formatting:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostringstream o;

    o << std::setiosflags(std::ios::fixed) << std::setprecision(2) << 0.1;

std::string s=o.str();
```

You will now find "0.10" in `s`.

If you do not know how many digits of precisions are significant as a result of whatever calculations you're doing, your only option is to use a dedicated library for fixed precision arithmetic, [like GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Floating point is, in practice, has a mantissa represented in binary (base 2).   One consequence of this is that `0.1` decimal (aka the fraction `1/10`) cannot be exactly represented in floating point.

The reason is the same as `1/3` cannot be represented exactly in a fixed number of decimal places - it is an infinitely recurring value `0.3333333.....`, and truncating it to a finite number of places introduces an error.   The only difference is that `1/10` is a infinitely recurring value in base 2.   So it cannot be represented exactly in a finite number of binary digits.

There are obviously other values affected in such a way (such as `0.2`, `0.6`, etc).    Such errors are an inherent property of floating point representations .... or, to put it another way, floating point represents an approximation (the value with a potential lack of precision).   And, when doing a sequence of calculations, the errors in the values propagate.

Since there is no way to exactly represent the value `0.1` in floating point (and other values), there is no way to exactly store a floating point value into a database and get a value that is exactly `0.1`.

You can try printing the value in a way that limits the precision of output, such as

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

std::ostringstream o;

o << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << result;

std::string s=o.str();
```

Bear in mind this controls how `result` is formatted (e.g. on output to a string in this case).   It does not change the value of `result`.

Notionally, the string `s` can be stored in your database .... if the field represents a string rather than a numeric value.

Answer (score -1):

the value is stored `47.600002288` for precision, but when you want to use it you can use just N digits after the floating point, for example if the value is (47.600002288) in `printf` use:

```
printf("%.2f\n", result);
```

this will print `47.60`, notice the `.2` after `%` it tell the formatting function to print 2 number after the floating point.

Note that you can print it directly to a string using `sprintf`:

```
char s= malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
sprintf(s, "%.2f\n", result);
//s contains "47.60"
```

In this case you have to be aware of the `malloc` parameter i used `sizeof(char)*10` this means that the character length must be under or equal 9 (cause the last character is reserved for string ending char `\0`).